# On with scenario onBillingServiceDisconnected is called?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

does the `onBillingServiceDisconnected` will be call right after the `BillingClient.startConnection` if something went wrong? or say differently does `BillingClient.startConnection,` **in case of error**, will always fire `onBillingSetupFinished` with `billingResult = error` or it's will call `onBillingServiceDisconnected` instead ?

Answer (score 0):

`onBillingServiceDisconnected` will be called when there's a connection already, but it gets lost. You can test this by clearing Google Play's data while your app is open. You should retry at this point to get the connection back.

`onBillingSetupFinished` with an error code will be called when you are trying to connect, but it failed. No connection existed beforehand. Depending on the error code you may want to retry here as well. [Check the codes here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.BillingResponseCode).